# Не понял объяснения в книге

Tags: алгоритм

Читаю книгу "Алгоритмы. Руководство по разработке." авторства Стивена Скиена.
На 35 странице приведено доказательство алгоритма для инкрементации натуральных чисел. Не смог полностью понять конечное уравнение.
Алгоритм:

[image: Алгоритм]

Обоснование и в конце уравнение которое я и не понял:
[image: Обоснование]

Comment: Во-первых выложи не скрин, а текст цитатой. во-вторых ты хоть напиши **что именно** ты не понял.

Comment: Последнее уравнение. Конкретнее вторая и третья строка. Было m + 1/2 стало просо m. Потом m заменилось на m + 1.

Comment: Тоже не смогла понять..(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Было m + 1/2 стало просто m

Там стоит округление вниз для всего выражения `(m+1/2)`. Поскольку m - целое число, то результат округления вниз суммы `(m+1/2)` будет равно m

> > Потом m заменилось на m + 1.

Функция `Increment` возвращает значение параметра, увеличенное на 1. То есть `Increment(m) = m+1`, что и было выполнено в формуле

Вообще последняя формула доказывает, что `y+1=2Increment(округление вниз(y/2))`, если y - нечетное число. Как это делается. Представим `y=2m+1` (это как свойства нечетных чисел), а теперь подставим это в выражение

```
2Increment(округление вниз(y/2)) = 
2Increment(округление вниз((2m+1)/2)) = 
2Increment(округление вниз(m+1/2)) = // как уже написал, округление вниз(m+1/2) = m, то есть
2Increment(m) = // далее Increment(m) = m+1, значит
2(m+1)=2m+2 = y+1
```

По итогу вышло, что `2Increment(округление вниз(y/2)) = y+1` для нечетных y, что и требовалось доказать.